# GitHub Actions, trigger when all status checks for a Pull Request are complete

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to integrate a GitHub Actions flow that runs when all pull request status checks are complete. We are using a 3rd party CI tool to run builds & tests and currently have status checks at the end of a Pull Request to ensure they have passed before allowing the PR to be merged.

I am trying to setup a GitHub Actions workflow that is triggered based on these status checks being completed, but using either `check_run` or `status` do not seem to trigger.

```
name: Run integration tests
run-name: Run integration tests
on:
  status:
  check_run:

jobs:
  deploy-to-integration:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy-workflow.yml
    with:
      deployment_arguments: ...
    secrets: inherit
```

[image: All status checks completed, but not GitHub Actions has triggered]

Comment: `status` sounds right, what are you doing in the corresponding workflow?

Comment: @BenjaminW. It does not seem to mater what I am doing, it doesn't run, but I will edit the question to add

Comment: How are you trying to correlate a status with a specific PR? You have to show the details of `deploy-worfklow.yml`. On its own, `status` isn't associated with a PR, so if you set an additional status yourself, you first have to figure out which PR the status belongs to. And that depends on the payload, which is different from provider to provider.

Comment: But should it not be this workflow that is triggered based on the steps? I am not setting any status, it was my understanding that status waited for the commit status checks to complete, clearly I am wrong then. If this is the case, do you know of any way to trigger this Action when a PR has all checks completed?

Comment: Is that workflow merged into the default branch? `status` only triggers for workflows in there.

Comment: Yeah a version of it is, the `status` trigger is not in the default branch, but there is a workflow with that name there, I am able to trigger a manual dispatch in this branch, and am able to run it on a per-commit basis.

Comment: But that's the reason then, right? Docs for reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#status ("Note: This event will only trigger a workflow run if the workflow file is on the default branch.")